# Dotted line outside the imageView doesn't fit when image inserted

Tags: android, xml, image, android-imageview

I have a form in which you can insert image. I put dotted line outside the `imageview` which in xml inside the drawable. I also used a class which the image will fit inside the imageview. Now when i tried to insert an image inside the imageview it can successfully insert an image but the dotted line didn't adjust based on the size of the image.

`class of image to fit inside the imageView`

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

`XML file for the stroke`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#cccccc"
            android:dashWidth="10dp"
            android:dashGap="6dp" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
             android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

`content_main.xml` for image view

```
<junienegentien2015.android.ourthesis.com.detailsform.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/container_with_dotted_border"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted_border"
            android:src="@drawable/grm_upload"/>
```

`Before`
[image: before]

`After` notice the lines both sides
[image]

Comment: looks like your image isn't square, but rectangle. And you force `height = width` in custom view.

Comment: @Veaceslav Gaidarji, Sir is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: you can add padding to your image view 10dp or 20 dp then the src image will automatically gets inside dotted line